# Why my bokeh plots doesn't work on github?

Tags: python, git, github, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I have a private repo on github and I am experimenting with bokeh. I edit the file in my ipython notebook locally and I can see the plot working. When I push them on github and try to visualize it online I can see all the code except for the graph.

On nbviewer I can see other notebooks using bokeh. Is there any difference between the github rendering engine and nbviewer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is old, but if someone comes across it in the future...

There are two possibilities:

1. GitHub does not support dynamic output that uses Javascript, custom CSS, etc.

   http://blog.jupyter.org/2015/05/07/rendering-notebooks-on-github/

   > Second, because of security concerns, some features available on nbviewer will not be available on GitHub. For example, GitHub will not render any dynamic output display that uses JavaScript, custom CSS, and most custom HTML embedded in Markdown or in outputs. When this is the case, and GitHub cannot fully render your notebooks, you will see an icon that allows you to view the full notebook on nbviewer.
2. When you view the notebook locally, it is probably linked to an Ipython kernel, so Python is used to display the graphs. When you view it on GitHub, there is no Ipython kernel, so the graphs cannot be generated. Only simple static figures (such as matplotlib figures) will be seen in a static notebook.