# How to generate static Bokeh plots in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am trying to use Bokeh plots in my jupyter notebooks on github. However, because [github does not support dynamic output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518342/why-my-bokeh-plots-doesnt-work-on-github/34114969), I've needed hacky workarounds like loading an [exported plot](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html) into the markdown or hosting the html elsewhere.

Is it possible to write a python function which outputs the image without saving an `image.png` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bokeh 0.12.15 there is an internal function which can do the heavy lifting here. Note that the function is undocumented, so it's probably not meant to be used externally.

After installing the additional export requirements of [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/installation.html), [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) and [phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt), you can run the following to get a static plot:

`from bokeh.io.export import get_screenshot_as_png
get_screenshot_as_png(obj, driver=None)`

Comment: It is included in the reference guide, but is missing a docstring (please feel free to contribute one!) It's not expected to be of wide general interest, which is why it is tagged as part of the "dev" API. But being tagged at all means that it is a stable defended API that will not change.

Comment: @bigreddot that sounds great, thank you! I'll put in a PR after work to add a docstring. As a note, I actually know more than one user who gave up on Bokeh for one of the other plotting packages because of problems viewing plots on github. I'll let them know about this as well.

Comment: Right, GitHub scrubs all JavaScript content from its preview pages, and this is unfortunately outside our control.